# Is it a good practice to use triple quotes to create "docstrings" in non-standard contexts?

Tags: python, comments, pep8, docstring

I am looking at someone's code which has this kind of "docstrings" all over the place:

```
SLEEP_TIME_ON_FAILURE = 5
"""Time to keep the connection open in case of failure."""

SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 15
"""Socket timeout for inherited socket."""

...
```

As per the Python documentation, docstrings are applicable only in the context of the beginning of a module, class, or a method.

What is the implication of the above non-standard practice?  Why does Python allow this?  Doesn't this have performance impact?

Comment: It's allowed and it's fine.

Comment: It's legal because they're just strings, but I'd prefer to use comments there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as Python is concerned, these aren't docstrings. They're just string literals used as expression statements. You can do that - you can use any valid Python expression as its own statement. Python doesn't care whether the expression actually does anything. For a string on its own line, the only performance impact is a very small amount of extra work at bytecode compilation time; there's no impact at runtime, since these strings get optimized out.

Some documentation generators do look at these strings. For example, the very common [Sphinx autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute) extension will parse these strings to document whatever is directly above them. Check whether you're using anything like that before you change the code.

Answer (score 4):

In python, the `"""` is syntax for a multi-line string.

```
s1 = """This is a multi-line string."""
s2 = """This is also a multi-line
string that stretches 
across multiple lines"""
```

If these strings are not stored into a variable, then they are immediately garbage collected, and are essentially ignored, but they still use some overhead. On the other hand, comments using `#` are actually completely ignored by the interpreter.

The only exception to this rule is when this docstring comes immediately after a **function or class definition**, or on top of a **module**. In that case, it is stored in the special variable `__doc__`.

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings),

> Documentation Strings
>   Conventions for writing good documentation strings (a.k.a. "docstrings") are immortalized in PEP 257.
>
> Write docstrings for all public modules, functions, classes, and methods. Docstrings are not necessary for non-public methods, but you should have a comment that describes what the method does. This comment should appear after the def line.

Comment: "If these strings are not stored into a variable, then they are immediately garbage collected, and are essentially ignored, but they still use some overhead" - actually, the entire statement gets optimized out. There's no runtime overhead.

Comment: @user2357112: is this documented?

Comment: @codeforester: Probably not. Optimizer details usually aren't. [You can see it in the bytecode disassembly, though.](https://ideone.com/2ptMCT)

Comment: [Or you can take Guido's word for it](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

In those cases you should use a in-line comment, which the PEP8 style guide clearly defines https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments, e.g.:

```
SLEEP_TIME_ON_FAILURE = 5  # Time to keep the connection open in case of failure

SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 15  # Socket timeout for inherited socket
```

Comment: Your PEP 8 link doesn't actually support your assertion.

Comment: sorry, what I meant is in those cases you should use a in-line comment, which the PEP8 style guide clearly defines, I will edit answer accordingly